# Error: invalid command name ".!label" usando Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo una interfaz que requiere de un contador o cuenta regresiva. Por ahorita funciona todo bien, sin embargo, cuando cierro la ventana me salta este error: `invalid command name ".!label"`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? La verdad no se si es la label o algo así.
Aquí está mi código:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import font
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Entrenamiento")
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.geometry('1000x700+300+50')
root.configure(background='#6dd5ed')

# Countdown
lbl_seconds = Label(root, font=("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", 30), background='#6dd5ed')
lbl_seconds.pack(pady=10)

def update():
    for i in range(3, -1, -1):

        lbl_seconds['text'] = i

        if i == 3:
            lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#50c700'
        elif i == 2:
            lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#e8f300'
        else:
            lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#ff0000'
    
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)

for i in range(30, -1, -1):
    lbl_seconds['foreground'] = 'white'
    lbl_seconds['text'] = i
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.5)




update()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

Hay varios errores en tu código:

- Si cierras la ventana antes del final del conteo regresivo, el for aun sigue ejecutandose e intenta modificar un Label que ya no existe (de ahí el error del que vienes a pedir ayuda).
- La función update solo es llamada una vez. Puede ser que hayas querido llamarla cada segundo que pase?
- La cuenta regresiva que ves es de cada medio segundo, pues lo que se ejecuta es el time.sleep(0.5) del bucle for.

El consejo que doy, es que nunca uses time.sleep junto a Tkinter. Eso hace que el programa esté inactivo durante el tiempo indicado. Eso significa que la interfaz grafica no se dibujará ni procesará eventos (como clics) hasta que pase el tiempo.

Tkinter viene con un método universal (que todo widget tiene) llamado after, cuyo primer argumento son los milisegundos a "esperar" y el segundo es la función a llamar cuando pase el tiempo. Cualquier argumento adicional será pasado a la función. Esto pone a una función en espera sin interrumpir el bucle de eventos interno.

#### Solución

La idea de esta solución es hacer que se llame una función, la función hará lo que tenga que hacer y se hará llamar a si misma dentro de 1000 milisegundos y así hasta que el contador (que habremos estado pasando como argumento) llegue a 0.

Quité los imports no relevantes para la prueba.

Hice una prueba con 10 segundos de cuenta atras y funciona bien!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title("Entrenamiento")
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.geometry('1000x700+300+50')
root.configure(background='#6dd5ed')

# Countdown
lbl_seconds = Label(root, font=("Yu Gothic UI Semibold", 30), background='#6dd5ed')
lbl_seconds.pack(pady=10)

def update(i):
    lbl_seconds['text'] = i

    if i == 3:
        lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#50c700'
    elif i == 2:
        lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#e8f300'
    elif i == 1:
        lbl_seconds['foreground'] = '#ff0000'
    elif(i == 0):
        return

    lbl_seconds.after(1000, update, i - 1)

update(10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada UltimateDystrom